# I have age variable in dataset and i want to categorize the variable into "young","adult","old"

Tags: python

this is the code I was trying, but couldn't make it

```
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90]
lables =["young","adult","old"]
train['age'] = pd.cut(train.age,bins,labels = labels,include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking, could you clarify?

Comment: I have a dataset called train in which there is variable age range(0-90) I need to categorize the age variable into young, adult, old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code that I believe does what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.DataFrame(columns=['age'], data = [10,50,50,80])
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90]
labels =["young","adult","old"]
train['age'] = pd.cut(train.age,bins,labels = labels,include_lowest=True)
```

output:

```
    age
0   young
1   adult
2   adult
3   old
```